# Retrieving Profile Photos From Graph For Multiple Users Simultaneously Using RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, microsoft-graph-api

I have an ASP.NET Core API that returns a list of users to an Angular service. The user objects returned contain a handful of properties (id, firstName, lastName).

I would like my Angular service to retrieve this list from my API endpoint, and then query Microsoft Graph for the profiles pictures of all the returned users. I'm having trouble finding the correct way to do this with RxJs.

The order of options should be this:

- The Angular service makes an HTTP call to the API
- The API returns a list of users
- The Angular service iterates over the returned list of users and makes a call for **each one** to the Microsoft Graph endpoint for retrieving the profile picture of each user
- The information returned from the API and the profile picture blob are mapped into a single Typescript object
- The angular service returns a an observable array of the mapped object (user info from API and profile picture blob from Graph endpoint)

I'm specifically looking for the RxJs operator to use in order to:

1. Perform a foreach on an array of values
2. Perform an HTTP call for each element in the array
3. Map the original call to the API and the associated HTTP call to Graph into an object containing information from both calls

So far I'm able to retrieve the array from the API of users:

```
public getEligibleContractors(): Observable<EligibleContractor[]> {
    return this.http.get<ListEligibleContractorsResponse>(`${this.endpointUrl}/eligible`, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      take(1),
      map((response: HttpResponse<ListEligibleContractorsResponse>) => {
        return (response.body as ListEligibleContractorsResponse).eligibleContractors
      })
    );
  }
```

I now need to take this array of eligible contractors and make a call to Microsoft Graph for each element.

Currently the working function above returns an Observable of EligibleContractor[] but this will eventually be mapped into User[], an array of users with properties such as id, firstName, lastName, and profilePicture (blob).

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question on Reddit and got a great answer from a user over there. Was exactly what I was looking for. Posting here in case it'll help anyone else out with a similar problem:

Here's the [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/angular/comments/1ae35b5/rxjs_how_to_run_an_array_of_observables_based_on/) on Reddit.

And here's the solution:

```
this.users$ = this.getUsers().pipe(
      mergeAll(),
      mergeMap((user) =>
        this.getBlob(user.blobId).pipe(
          map((blob) => ({ ...user, blobURL: blob.picture }))
        )
      ),
      toArray()
    );
```